# Read Content in SharePoint from Drupal

Tags: sharepoint-integration, drupal

My client is already having a website powered by SharePoint and would like to re-develop the web site using Drupal. But still use SharePoint to host the content.

Q: How can I access SharePoint via Drupal?

Note: I know this topic was discussed before, but those posts/answers are 5-7 years old. So, I'm looking for a contemporary answer.

Comment: I think migration of the content is best option... Why not?